# What is boron classified as a electronegative element and a electropositive element?

Tags: electronegativity

What is boron classified as  a electronegative element  or a electropositive element?

Is electronegativity a relative concept ? Why is it that sometimes we treat Boron as an electronegative element and sometimes as a electropositive element?

Comment: Electronegativity is relative.

Comment: Boron is more electronegative than the metals but less electronegative than the non-metals, generally.

Comment: hi, you again! is it why we treat it electronegative and electropositive @DHMO

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Everything is electronegative and electropositive (except caesium and fluorine).

Comment: caesium and fluorine are electronegative, i guess

Comment: Caesium is the least electronegative and fluorine the most.

Comment: are low electronegative elements, electropositive or neutral? @DHMO

Comment: Do you know what electronegativity means?

Comment: :( i Know that electronegative element attract electrons.

Comment: ok got it, cannot be electropositive, but will it be neutral?

Comment: Then before it attracts electrons it is neutral and after it attracts electrons it is negatively charged.

Comment: "electropositive" and "electronegative" are not charges.

Comment: How is it unclear, what Vedant is asking? It may previously have been so, but it seems clear now, and you've only just put it on hold...

Answer (score 4):

When you think about electronegativity, think of it as a **relative** value, meaning in comparison to atoms of other elements. Therefore, Boron is more electronegative than the metals but less electronegative than the non-metals, in general.

> Fluorine is used as the standard with which to compare the relative
>   electronegativities of other elements.

Everything is electronegative and electropositive. Caesium is the least electronegative and fluorine the most.

Comment: Could you rephrase it instead of just copying my words.

Comment: if you want to add your answer go ahead, i will remove mine and also upvote yours @DHMO

Comment: No, I just asked you to elaborate instead of copying my words because my words are meant to be short notes to make you think.

Comment: ok @DHMO doing jst that